# 'gameObject' is not a member of 'Object'.

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

hi i write this code in unity android an unity give me error :

```
var root : Transform;

function Awake() {
    for (child in root)
    {
        child.gameObject.AddComponent(SphereCollider);
        child.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
    }
}
```

unity error : 'gameObject' is not a member of 'Object'.

i dont know how to fix this error , please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because Unity creates `child` as a variable of type `Object`, which of course doesn't have a `gameObject` property.
I think you need to specify a type for the variable `child` in your loop (btw, [the documentation does this, too](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)), like this:

```
for (var child : Transform in transform) {
    child.gameObject.AddComponent(SphereCollider);
    child.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
}
```